# How to target first of two possible types in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I target either the first P or H2 in a container div but ignore both if another element exists above them?

For example

Targets h2:

```
<div class = "container">
<h2>I'm doing great</h2>
<p>Love working with CSS</p>
</div>
```

Targets Only p:

```
<div class = "container">
<p>Love working with CSS</p>
</div>
```

Targets Nothing:

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "crazy-custom wiget>I apreciate stackoverflow</div>
<h2>I'm doing great</h2>
<p>Love working with CSS</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
    h2:first-child,
    p:first-child {
        // styles
    }
```

The selectors above affect those `h2` and `p` elements that are first children of their parent.

Answer (score 2):

`p:first-child, h2:first-child` will target those elements only when they are the first child of their parent element.